# Algebraic group associated to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-groups

According to Milne's *Algebraic Groups*, it is possible to define an algebraic $K$-group as a functor from a small category of finitely generated $K$-algebras to the category of groups.
I am interested in defining an algebraic group which would play the role of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ (although I am not sure what that sentence means).

Using this functorial approach, I would set

$$R\mapsto R^+/2R^+,$$

where $R^+$ denotes the underlying abelian group structure of $R$ and $2R^+$ is the image of the morphism $r\mapsto 2r$.

The first question is: *Is this definition correct?*

If so, then: *What is the schematic description of this algebraic group?*

Comment: if $Char(K)\not=2$ then 2 is invertible and hence the group you defined is the trivial group. if $Char(K)=2$ then $2=0$ and the group you defined is the additive group $G_a$. in both cases it is not a good analog of $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$

Comment: @ali very true. I'm considering $K=\mathbb R$, so we are in the first case. Do you know of a good alternative??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you forget one important issue in the definition: What you define called a group functor we call it a $K$- group if it is representable, i. e., if there is a scheme $Y$ over $K$ such that your functor send $R$ to $Hom(Spec\, R,Y)$. Not every functor is representable. For example, it is easy to see that the group functor $R\to \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$ is not representable: If it were representable by $Y$, we should have
$$\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}=Hom(Spec\,k\times k,Y)=Hom(Spec\, k,Y)\times Hom(Spec k,Y)=\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z},$$
which is a contradiction.

Second, you want an analog of $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$, but what is $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$? It is the unique group such that for every other group $G$, $Hom(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z},G)$ is the $2$-torsion of $G$. so you have to find a group with a similar property. The group functor we defined in the last paragraph was a  good candidate, but it is not a $K$-group scheme. But if you look at the problem, you can see that the problem is that the schemes can be disconnected. The same problem happens in the definition of the constant sheaf. The solution is simple: Let's denote by $n_R$ the number of connected components of $Spec\,R$ and define a group functor $R\to (\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z})^{n_R}$.

It is easy to see that this functor is representable by $Y=Spec (K\times  K)$. Gor the group structure, keep in mind that $Y$ has two points and they should be associated with the two elements of $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$, so define the coproduct
$$K\times K\to (K\times K)\otimes (K\times K)$$ to be the map
$$(1,0)\to (1,0)\otimes (1,0)+(0,1)\otimes(0,1),(0,1)\to (1,0)\otimes (0,1)+(0,1)\otimes (1,0)$$

This group is called the constant group scheme $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$ and has the universal property we want: It can detect the $2$-torsion of group schemes.

Comment: I'd like to add that a quick search on Google for _constant group scheme Z/2Z_ provides a 67-page pdf called _Introduction to Finite Group Schemes_ as the first result, which ', among other things, includes a general construction for the scheme analogue of an arbitrary finite group. In this context, the solution of $Spec (K\times K)$ given by @ali corresponds to the cardinality of the group.

Comment: Are you sure the scheme structure is $\operatorname{Spec}(K\times K)$? With your answer, I've realised Milne does solve my question, he defines the constant algebraic group over a field $K$ corresponding to a finite group, and the way he does it is slightly different: he takes the disjoint union of $|G|$ copies of $\operatorname{Spec} K$. The underlying topological space is then the same, but I think the structure sheaf is different from the one you propose.

Comment: In the simplest case of $G=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and, if I'm not wrong, $$\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}(K\times K)}(\{((1,0))\})= \left\{\frac{a_1,a_2}{b_1,b_2}\middle | a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\in K \mbox{ and } b_2\neq 0 \right\},$$ while $$\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec} K \coprod \operatorname{Spec} K}(\{((1,0))\}) \cong K.$$

Comment: I think you don't know how localisation work in non- integral ring.$(1,0).(0,1)=0$  hence when you invert$(0,1)$ , $\frac{(1,0)}{(1,1)}=0$ and hence the local ring become isomorphic to K.

Comment: very true! In the above, $$\frac{(a_1,a_2)}{(b_1,b_2)}=\frac{(0,a_2)}{(0,b_2)}.$$ What surprises me then is that these constant algebraic groups are all affine.

Comment: well, it is not that surprising. we are talking about finite groups and every finite scheme is affine. it is an easy exercise in algebraic geometry

Comment: Never heard about it. But if it's a standard one it'll be in Hartshorne. I'll have a look at it. Thanks again.